# Get lastModifiedDate() and fileSize() of files in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, file

I have the following Method:

```
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        final RelativeLayout mFrame3 =  (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate( R.layout.ptrip, container, false );

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc/");
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(folder.getAbsolutePath());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), FilesInFolder.get(0).toString(), 2000).show(); //display filename (0)
////////////////////////
///////////////////////
//would this work:
//for (int i = 0; i <= FilesInFolder.length(); i++) {
//long lastTime = FilesInFolder[0].lastModified();
//String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString(); //last modified date?
//String sizeString = getReadableSize(FolderInFiles[i].length()); //file size?
//}
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
        lv = (ListView) mFrame3.findViewById(R.id.lvFiles);

        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Clicking on items
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + (position + 1) + ": ID" + v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return mFrame3;
    }
```

My GetFolder function is:

```
public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
    ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File(DirectoryPath);


    //f.mkdirs();
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    if (files.length == 0)
        return null;
    else {
        for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++)  {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".tol")) {
                long lastTime = files[i].lastModified();
                String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString();
                String sizeString = getReadableSize(files[i].length());
                //String fileName = files[i].getName().substring(0, files[i].getName().lastIndexOf("."));
                MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());
                //MyFiles.add("Trip Name: " + fileName + "\nTrip Taken On: " + dateString + "\n" + sizeString);
            }
        }
    }

    return MyFiles;
}
```

How do I get the `fileSize` and `lastModifiedDate` inside the `onCreateMethod`? I commented out the `fileSize` and `lastModifiedDate` inside the `GetFolder` method because I am trying to get the filename only so I can read the file inside `onCreate` method to display the ASCII contents of it in a MultiLine EditText.

Would this work in `onCreate` as added above:

```
//display filename (0)
////////////////////////
///////////////////////
//would this work:
//for (int i = 0; i <= FilesInFolder.length(); i++) {
//long lastTime = FilesInFolder[0].lastModified();
//String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(lastTime)).toString(); //last modified date?
//String sizeString = getReadableSize(FolderInFiles[i].length()); //file size?
//}
//////////////////////
//////////////////////
```

Comment: Don't use `String` to represent a file, use a `List<File>` and only if you need to display the filename get each file's name.

Comment: Right now the function is returning the filename with extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options

- If you do not want to change `GetFiles`: In `onCreate`, create a `File` instance from the file names, and call the methods there. This is the only option, if you cannot change `GetFiles` for whatever reason.
- Create a class `MyFile` which has three fields (`name`, `fileSize` and `lastModifiedDate`), and return a `List<MyFile>` from `GetFiles`. Generally speaking this option is useful, if you only want to return a limited subset of properties or read-only views of an instance (without setters for example).
- Return a `List<File>` from `GetFiles`

The last option is simple and idiomatic.

Comment: I am thinking of calling three separate method for Filename, File Last Modified, File Size and see how it works out. Thanks.

Comment: I called three separate method for three separate variables. It worked. I'll convert it into one later on :)